# How to make element that containes some special pair be first in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have JSON array created having code like `user_images.push({'href' : value.href, 'title'  : value.title });` in some for_each loop. I wonder how to make element containing something like `'href' : my_href` first in the array?

Comment: It's an object. Why do you need them in a specific order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array to find the object with specific value, then remove it from the array and insert as first:

```
$.each( user_images, function( index ) {
    if( this.href === my_href ) {
        user_images.unshift( user_images.splice( index, 1 )[0] );
        return false; //stop the loop
    }
});
```

`user_images[0].href` should be `my_href` now

Comment: +1 for noticing the jQuery tag, which I did not until _after_ posting my answer. (Oh well, now there're with and without answers...)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a "JSON array", you have a JavaScript array (JSON is a string representation of data).

But anyway, what you seem to be saying is that you have an array, `user_images`, which contains objects that each have an `href` property, and you want to make it so that the object with a particular `href` property is first in the array. The particular value you are looking for is stored in a variable called `my_href`. If I've got that right, read on...

I'm guessing your current code looks a little like this:

```
var user_images = [];
for (value in someObjectThatYouDoNotShowInYourQuestion)
   user_images.push({'href' : value.href, 'title' : value.title });
```

To find the item in the array that has an `href` equal to the variable `my_href` you can simply loop through the array until you find that item and then use the [`.splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove it from its current position and the [`unshift()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add it to the beginning of the array:

```
var item,
    i;
for (i = 0; i < user_images.length; i++) {
   if (user_images[i].href === my_href) {
      item = user_images[i];
      user_images.splice(i,1);
      user_images.unshift(item);
      break;
   }
}
```

If no matching item is found the array will be unchanged.

Note: You don't actually need the `item` variable shown in my code. I put it in for readability, to make it obvious that you are storing a reference to the object you were looking for, then removing it, then putting it in at the beginning of the array, but given that the `.splice()` method returns an array of the removed item(s) you can replace those three lines within the `for` loop with this single line:

```
user_images.unshift(user_images.splice(i,1)[0]);
```